# PHP not performing UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I created a database with user's first name, last name, email, and temp password. When a user logs in for  the first time they are shown a profile with the information already in the database as well as some additional fields they must fill in. On clicking submit the form should then update their profile in the database but it doesn't. The database is called 'users'. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <?php
$testerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$tester = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["tester"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters

include "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$testerID' AND username='$tester' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $email = $row['email'];

$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tester Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="886">
  <tr>
    <td width="876"><h1>Welcome 
    <?php  
    echo $fname;
    ?> 
    to the Closed Beta</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="content">
<?php
$date = getdate();
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['$new_password'])) {
    $new_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $new_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_password']);
    $phone_model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_model']);
    $carrier = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carrier']);

    $sql_update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$new_email', password='$new_password', phone_model='$phone_model', carrier='$carrier' WHERE id='$testerID'");
}
if(is_null($test_start)){ 
    echo "
    <form action=\"index.php\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" name=\"myForm\" id=\"myform\" method=\"post\">
    <table width=\"90%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"6\">
      <tr>
        <td width=\"20%\" align=\"right\">ID: </td>
        <td width=\"80%\"><label>
          $testerID 
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Username: </td>
        <td><label>
          $tester
          </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">First Name: </td>
        <td><label>
          $fname
          </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Last Name: </td>
        <td><label>
          $lname
          </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Email Address: </td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"\"/>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Old password: (the one you were assigned)</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"old_password\" id=\"old_password\" value=\"$password\"/>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">New Password: </td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"new_password\" id=\"newPassField\" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Confirm New Password: </td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"confirm_password\" id=\"newPassField\" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Phone Model: </td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"phone_model\" id=\"phone_model\" value=\"$phone_model\"/> (a 4 digit number)
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=\"right\">Carrier: </td>
        <td><label>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"carrier\" id=\"carrier\" cols=\"64\" rows=\"5\" value=\"$carrier\"/>
          </label></td>
      </tr>
          <input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" id=\"button\" value=\"Update\" />
    </table>
    </form>";   
}else{

}
?>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables for layout? Seriously?

Comment: `preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]);` is not a replacement for `mysql_real_escape_string()`. I suggest sticking to one tried an true escaping function.  And storing you password in **the clear** is a very bad idea. Use a salted hash instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is an error in your sql then the best way to find out what it is, is to add in error checking code

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

i have added it to the end of your query here

```
$sql_update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$new_email', password='$new_password', phone_model='$phone_model', carrier='$carrier' WHERE id='$testerID'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks bumperbox. Using the error check I discovered I had to enter information in all fields before I clicked submit. I was only testing by filling in one field at a time. If all fields were not filled in the POST failed. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

You have `isset($_POST['$new_password'])` instead of `isset($_POST['new_password'])`. Notice the added `$`

Answer (score 1):

Where have you defined your `mysql_select_db` for the DB selection?

Also, I'm not quite used to apply for `UPDATE` selections, but you could use `INSERT` with a `DUPLICATE` value, if you know the ids or a similar column that is fixed for each user. Something like:

`$query = "INSERT INTO users (_columns_) VALUES (_$columns_) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE _column_='_$column_'";`

Changing your columns and the posted values from the form with a post method, of course. Add there a `WHERE` clause if needed, even thought that would be something to look for on the db.

Comment: Thanks going to give this a whirl